# Server 2003 stuck booting, won't go past "DHCP.." See Screenshot

Tags: windows

We have a really old Windows 2003 Server with raid 5. We replaced a failed disc a couple of days ago and it was running fine but it just conked out. See image for how far we get before it reboots itself and tries again. This is our main DC so any help is EXTREMELY appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You aren't even getting to Windows, the computer is attempting to boot from the network because C: is not bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the raid configuration and see if the raid is configured properly and active (bootable). If so then you have to put a backup back.

Comment: Why are you thinking that there is a raid in place?

Comment: Because the OP said so in their post.

Answer (score 0):

You have dead storage, or the server can't find the storage.

I know you said you recently replaced a drive in your RAID 5 array.  As R.Nys says, double-check that your RAID is properly configured, active, in an optimal state, etc.

The fact that you replaced a drive a couple of days ago makes me suspect one of two things:

1. You've lost two or more drives on that array.  (Drives sometimes all die at the same time because they frequently come from the same "batch.")
2. You have a dead RAID card.  (I'm honestly inclined towards this if you never get to a RAID configuration screen, but it could still be #1.)

If it's #2, you might be able to put in a new card, recreate the array, and boot merrily, but it's also possible that you're about to use your backups.  (If it's #1, you're pretty much guaranteed to be using your backups.)  Sorry.  I hope they're good.

Since it's Windows Server 2003 and you admit yourself the hardware is really old, it's probably no longer under hardware support.  It might be worth your while to replace it with something newer.  (I assume this isn't the *only* DC when I say that.)  If you can't, you can't, but still, something to consider.